# Как заставить выполнять скрипт по разрешению экрана?

Tags: php, jquery

Есть код, хочу чтобы он выполнялся только для декстопов и планшетов, как сдлетаь так чтобы скрипт запускался если ширина экрана выше 600?

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var $menu = $("#menu");
     
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 150 && $menu.hasClass("default-norm") ){
        $menu.fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).removeClass("default-norm")
                   .addClass("fixed header--dark2")
                   .fadeIn('fast');
        });
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 150 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
        $menu.fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).removeClass("fixed header--dark2")
                   .addClass("default-norm")
                   .fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Почему просто не проверить ширину?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(document).width() > 600){
   
var $menu = $("#menu");
     
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 150 && $menu.hasClass("default-norm") ){
        $menu.fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).removeClass("default-norm")
                   .addClass("fixed header--dark2")
                   .fadeIn('fast');
        });
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 150 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
        $menu.fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $(this).removeClass("fixed header--dark2")
                   .addClass("default-norm")
                   .fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }
});  

}

});
```

Comment: добавил, но он вообще перестал работать оказывается)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   такая ошибка

Comment: @reddyk скобки не дописал в условие if, поправил

Comment: Благодарю, сам тоже не заметил